# Validating textInput widgets at client side - Gmail add on

Tags: google-apps-script, gmail-addons

Instead of validating inputs at the server, if we have something like
 `textInput.setRequired(true)` 
we could validate it at client side. Do we have something like this for widgets ? This would significantly conserve the number of http requests sent.

Comment: Why would you ever not validate inputs server side??

Comment: To reduce the load on the server. Client side validations are fast.

Comment: If you don't validate received input on the server, you are asking for someone to send you malicious payloads / bad data. It's one thing to reduce the invalid outgoing responses from your add-on, but it's completely different to not validate input server-side.

Comment: It's also unclear what you are attempting to validate (custom form submission?), and which server you want to avoid validating on, i.e. Google's Apps Script server vs. your personal server, etc.

Comment: I would like to validate required fields. I can do that in the server. But I just want to know if that's possible in the client side .